# How to pass a forms.timer into another class to be used simultaneously?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, class, timer

I have a timer in main that I would like to pass into a class called "Enemy". I wasn't really sure how to do it correctly. Here's what my code looks like.

My Timer called "mastertmr" in main calls "Click". Click calls "Enemy Spawn" and from there i would like to be able to spawn enemies on the same increments as my main timer. I pass it in as "tmr".

### MainWindow

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    character = new Character(Background, Dispatcher, keys, Display, 10);
    character.Place(200, 100);
    creatures = new List<Character>();
    enemies = new List<Enemy>();
    creatures.Add(character);
    Display.Content = character.X;
    random = new Random();

    enemymanager = new EnemyManager(Background, Dispatcher, keys, Display, **mastertmr** , 10);


    mastertmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    mastertmr.Interval = this.waitTime;
    mastertmr.Tick += new EventHandler(Click);
    mastertmr.Start();
}

public void Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //EnemyManager enemymanager;

    enemymanager.spawn();
}
```

---

### EnemyManager Class

```
class EnemyManager
{

    System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr;
    protected Dispatcher dispatcher;
    protected Canvas Background;
    protected Label Display;
    protected Int32 waitTime;
    protected Dictionary<String, String> keys;
    public int i;

    public EnemyManager(Canvas Background, Dispatcher dispatcher, Dictionary<String, String> keys, Label Display, System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr, Int32 waitTime =100)
    {
        this.Background = Background;
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
        this.keys = keys;
        this.waitTime = waitTime;
        this.tmr = tmr;
    }

    public void spawn()
    {


        tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(hi);
        tmr.Start();
        Enemy enemy;
        i++;

        if (i % 100 == 0)
        {
            enemy = new Enemy(Background, dispatcher, keys, Display, 10);

            enemy.Place(400, 0);
        }
    }


    public void hi(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Display.Content = "Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiisdfghdfgh";
    }

}
```

Comment: It's seems null (tmr argument) is passed to EnemyManager constructor? :)

Comment: Ah, so do you think i should pass it through spawn maybe?

Comment: I guess you don't need timer inside of EnemyManager class, window has timer tick handler and each time it ticks you can call Spawn method of EnemyManager. It's better approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do but I would avoid passing the timer through to the enemy classes. If you're trying to do more than one thing simultaneously per tick, I would just subscribe the "hi" method to the Tick event on the main class e.g.

```
enemymanager = new EnemyManager(Background, Dispatcher, keys, Display, 10);
mastertmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
mastertmr.Interval = this.waitTime;
mastertmr.Tick += new EventHandler(Click);
mastertmr.Tick += new EventHandler(enemymanager.hi);
mastertmr.Start();
```

Comment: Yeahhh this is what i wanted to do, i was just over complicating things in my head. Thank you.